# how can i login parse jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

i can not see anything please help me. 
How can i parse this code .
I can build cordova app .
i can parse everything app.js file but login doesnt work any ideas?

I think my js code wrong but where am i wrong ?

Cordova is new for me i have no experience for this

```js
$('#submmit-register').on('click', function () {
console.log('login');
 var username = $$('#register-username').val();
 var email = $$('#register-email').val();
 var password = $$('#register-password').val();

 if (!username || !password || !email){
  myApp.alert('Please fill in all Registration form fields');
  return;
 }


});

var query = 'http://-------/users/signup';
///'http://-------/users/login'
var postdata = {};

postdata.username = name;
postdata.email = email;
postdata.password = password;
myApp.showIndicator();
$.ajax({
 url: query,
 headers: {"X-Parse-Application-Id":applicationId,"X-Parse-REST-API-Key":restApiKey},
 type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json",
 data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
 statusCode: {
  201: success201,
  400: notsuccess,
  500: notsuccess
 }
});
```

```html
  <div class="popup popup-login">
    <div class="content-block-login">
      <h4>LOGIN</h4>
            <div class="loginform">
                <form id="LoginForm" method="post">
                <div class="form_row">
                <div class="form_row_icon"><img src="images/icons/white/user.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="username" />
                </div>
                <div class="form_row">
                <div class="form_row_icon"><img src="images/icons/white/lock.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="password" />
                </div>
                <div class="forgot_pass">
                  <a href="#" data-popup=".popup-forgot" class="open-popup">Forgot Password?</a></div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form_submit" id="submit" value="LOGIN" />
                </form>
                <div class="signup_social">
                <!--a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="signup_facebook external">FACEBOOK</a>
                <!--a href="http://www.twitter.com/" class="signup_twitter external">TWITTER</a->
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="signup_linkedin external">LINKEDIN</a>
                <!--a href="http://www.twitter.com/" class="signup_googleplus external">GOOGLE+</a-->

                      </div>
                <div class="signup_bottom">
                <p>Don't have an account?</p>
                <a href="#" data-popup=".popup-signup" class="open-popup">LOGIN</a>                </div>
            </div>
      <div class="close_loginpopup_button"><a href="#" class="close-popup"><img src="images/icons/white/menu_close.png" alt="" title="" /></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Register Popup -->
    <div class="popup popup-signup">
    <div class="content-block-login">
      <h4>REGISTER</h4>
            <div class="loginform">
            <form id="RegisterForm" method="post">
            <div class="form_row">
            <div class="form_row_icon"><img src="images/icons/white/user.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="username" />
            </div>
            <div class="form_row">
            <div class="form_row_icon"><img src="images/icons/white/contact.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form_row">
            <div class="form_row_icon"><img src="images/icons/white/lock.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="password" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form_submit" id="submit" value="REGISTER" />
            </form>
            <!--div class="signup_social">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="signup_facebook external">FACEBOOK</a>
            <!--a href="http://www.twitter.com/" class="signup_twitter external">TWITTER</a->
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="signup_linkedin external">LINKEDIN</a>
            <!--a href="http://www.twitter.com/" class="signup_googleplus external">GOOGLE+</a-->

          </div-->
            </div>
      <div class="close_loginpopup_button"><a href="#" class="close-popup"><img src="images/icons/white/menu_close.png" alt="" title="" /></a></div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Login Popup -->
    <div class="popup popup-forgot">
    <div class="content-block-login">
      <h4>FORGOT PASSWORD</h4>
            <div class="loginform">
            <form id="ForgotForm" method="post">
            <div class="form_row">
            <div class="form_row_icon"><img src="images/icons/white/contact.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
            <input type="text" name="Email" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="email" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form_submit" id="submit" value="RESEND PASSWORD" />
            </form>
            <div class="signup_bottom">
            <p>Check your email and follow the instructions to reset your password.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
      <div class="close_loginpopup_button"><a href="#" class="close-popup"><img src="images/icons/white/menu_close.png" alt="" title="" /></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Social Popup ->
```

Comment: is query='http://-------/users/signup', the value you are using or this was part of the code you removed to paste it here?

Comment: More information will be required. What exactly happens? What is expected? What are console logs etc. showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no `submmit-register` button or id found in your html code

You have used `var username = $$('#register-username').val();` double dollar sign, which is not valid in javascript

I am not sure if what is `myApp`

`myApp.showIndicator();` is a function then call it just like `showIndicator();`

`myApp.alert` is invalid

**Replace this with success function to get result in just single function**

```
statusCode: {
  201: success201,
  400: notsuccess,
  500: notsuccess
 }
```

**success function**

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```